# Create a common/shared microservice in nestjs

Tags: node.js, microservices, nestjs

How can i create a microservice that contains all the shared/common login/classes between projects?

I have a gateway, and different microservices, let say auth and account.
How can I share the `user.model` for example, considering that both services will use that entity?

Also considering that some common methods can be located in this common microservices in order to not have the code duplicated.

Comment: nestJS mono repo approach might help you https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo. you can create a common lib module and share it across all microservices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the library module of microservice in Nestjs

https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries

Here you can create a library module with the command

```
nest g library my-library
```

Then in that module, you can put the shared module like constant, util, etc which are common in all microservices.

To use that module import like this

```
import { MyLibraryModule } from '@app/my-library';
```

Comment: I have one doubt this is available for monorepo or to totally different microservices, and I need to manually copy the build of the library in each microservices?

Comment: it's for monorepo. You don't have to copy the build manually you just import it like any other library as shown above rest build process is handled by nest js itself.